# Array/Curve: How do I fix array modifier overlap when combining "Fit Curve" Setting with a Curve modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I am attempting to create an arena using the Archimesh addon and the curve modifier. I created a set of archways and columns with Archimesh, using the built in "create an array of elements" checkbox. I then set the Fit Type of the array modifier on the created objects to "Fit Curve", then add a curve modifier set to a bezier circle using the default settings.

My problem is that the start and end points of the object arrays overlap. 
[image: Endpoints of arrayed object overlap]

Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to make the circle bigger or the pieces smaller - there is no other way.You make the circle bigger by scaling it edit mode.You make the arrayed piece smaller also by scaling it in edit mode.

Comment: If the curve is circular, using the 'bend' option of the 'simple deform' modifier can be an alternative

Comment: if using relative offset, you can manually find an offset value that makes all pieces to fit the curve, even if they are no more connected. Eg, instead of offset 1, you could find that 1.0175 would make a good fit of the curve. Then, scale your object of that exact amount along the local axis used to fit the curve, and then reset the array offset back to 1. It may fit perfectly.